# Drush make and SVN: Leaving behind the .svn folders

Tags: drush

Maybe I am missing a parameter, but when I use the below code in my make file, the ".svn" folder is removed. I would like that folder to remain. How can I do this?

```
projects[module_name][type] = "module"
projects[module_name][download][type] = "svn"
projects[module_name][download][url] = svn+ssh://company.com/home/svn/drupal7modules/module_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--working-copy` option.

Help tekst: Preserves VCS directories, like .git, for projects downloaded using such methods.